# How to do a dropdownlist using a model which contains a list of other model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to create a DropDownList in my view which is using a specific model called `Projects`.

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `Company` repository and I need to list those companies in a view that uses the `ProjectModel` class as `@model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you'll need a `CompanyID` in your project model (I'll assume it's an int).
Secondly, you'll need a `List<SelectListItem>` that you can use for your Dropdown, so your model will look something like this:

```
public ProjectModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CompaniesSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return Companies
                .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = c.CompanyName,
                        Value = c.CompanyID.ToString(),
                        Selected = c.CompanyID == CompanyID
                    })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.CompanyID, Model.CompaniesSelectList, "Please Select")
```